# alignof(T) with T=__m512 is not equal to alignof(__m512)

Tags: c++, clang++

I ran into a strange situation that `alignof(__m512)` is not equal to `std::alignment_of<__m512>::value` compiled by Apple's clang. After some testing I found that when `alignof(T)` is evaluated inside a template with `T=__m512`, the result is different with direct `alignof(__m512)`.
I also ran several test compiled by g++ and non-Apple's clang on ubuntu(WSL) and got correct(I thought) behavior.
Is this a bug of Apple's clang or an issue about implemented behavior?

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h> //avx headers

#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

void test_directly() {
  printf("directly: typeid %s alignof %zu\n", typeid(__m512).name(), alignof(__m512));
}

template<typename T>
void test_as_template_argument() {
  static_assert(std::is_same<T, __m512>::value, "assert");
  printf("template: typeid %s alignof %zu\n", typeid(T).name(), alignof(T));
}

int main() {
  test_directly();
  test_as_template_argument<__m512>();
  return 0;
}
```

output(compiled with `clang++ -std=c++17 -march=native`):

```
directly: typeid Dv16_f alignof 64
template: typeid Dv16_f alignof 32
```

clang's version:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

macOS's version: `macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E2269) Darwin 19.4.0`

Comment: ["Regular clang"](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zWorKCEMCdHksiPp) also works correctly.

Comment: Are you compiling it on a machine that has AVX512?

Comment: @thedudehimself Yes.

Comment: Related: [D53207](https://reviews.llvm.org/D53207) & [`std::alignment_of<T>::value` might be different from `alignof(T)` #39061](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/39061), but it dates back to late 2018, yet clang v11 came out [late 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang#Status_history).

Comment: @thedudehimself why would that be relevant? I would expect to be able to cross-compile for a machine that has AVX512 even on a machine that does not.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug. You can get the desired behavior by wrapping `__m512` in a struct like this:

```
struct X { __m512 m; }
```